# Apply bash variables for directories (recursive)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a project that requires me to keep a lot of bash files with installation/maintenance/whatever scripts, and most of them need to know where other folders are. Right now that is all made with relative paths, but that makes me keep the folders structure, which might not be the best idea on the long run.

So, as an example, I have this file (`script.sh`):

```
THINGS_DIR=..\..\things
myprogram $THINGS_DIR
```

But now I would like to have 2 files, one with global variables from these directories (let's call it `conf.sh`):

```
THINGS_DIR=./things/
OTHERS_DIR=./things/others/
```

and, on `script.sh`, somehow, I would use those variables.

The best way I could find it's to keep that `conf.sh` in a fixed place and all of the others run it before it starts, but I was trying to find a better solution.

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that this is in a Git repository, which is a fair assumption to keep along the way. That being said and because I wanted to keep this as self contained as possible I ended up using this in every script that needs those variables:

```
. $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/my_conf_file.conf
```

This command executes what's inside my_conf_file.conf located in the git repository root. It's not ideal (nor completelly safe) but it does the trick with minimum configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common idiom is to have a config file in one (or more) of several directories and have your script check each one of them in order. For instance you could search:

```
/etc/script.cfg     # global
~/.script.cfg       # user-specific, hidden with leading dot
```

You might also search the environment as a last resort. This search strategy is very easy to implement in bash. All you have to do is:

```
[[ -e /etc/script.cfg ]] && . /etc/script.cfg
[[ -e ~/script.cfg    ]] && . ~/script.cfg

echo "THINGS_DIR=$THINGS_DIR"
echo "OTHERS_DIR=$OTHERS_DIR"
```

It sources the two config files if they exist. If the user copy exists it overrides the global settings. If neither exists, the script will naturally use any environment variables. This way the user could override the config settings like so:

```
THINGS_DIR=/overridden/things/dir script.sh
```